# Adding separator to bar border

Tags: jquery, html, css

What currently we have is something like

[image]

and the goal is the chart with the separator on both the ages like the following image

[image]

have used [Pure CSS Circular Percentage Bar](http://www.cssscript.com/pure-css-circular-percentage-bar/) plugin to achieve it.

And to add separator on both the ages of bar have tried giving:

> order, shadow, height, width

to the following class.

> .pie, .c100 .bar:after  .pie, .c100 .bar:before
>
> .c100 .slice:before  .c100 .slice:after

and so on with other elements but didn't get the success.

And fiddle for the same is https://jsfiddle.net/bhavikvaishnani/r7emrhv8/6/

```css
.pie,
.c100 .bar {
  position: absolute;
  border: 0.08em solid #307bbb;
  width: 0.84em;
  height: 0.84em;
  clip: rect(0em, 0.5em, 1em, 0em);
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.c100 {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 120px;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0.1em 0.1em 0;
  background-color: #cccccc;
}

.c100>span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 5em;
  line-height: 5em;
  font-size: 0.2em;
  color: #cccccc;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-transition-property: all;
  -moz-transition-property: all;
  -o-transition-property: all;
  transition-property: all;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  -o-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.c100:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.08em;
  left: 0.08em;
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  width: 0.84em;
  height: 0.84em;
  -webkit-transition-property: all;
  -moz-transition-property: all;
  -o-transition-property: all;
  transition-property: all;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  -o-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in;
}

.c100 .slice {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  clip: rect(0em, 1em, 1em, 0.5em);
}

.c100.p25 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="c100 p25"> <span>25%</span>
  <div class="slice">
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="fill"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Need the solution in a way we can dynamically change the value of percentage.

Comment: I would like to suggest you to use D3 charts instead of these charts. There you will get more varieties and functionalities.

Answer (score 6):

You can add  in .bar:before and .bar:after

```
.c100 .bar:before {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  left: -10px;
  top: 47px;
  width: 10px;
}

.c100 .bar:after {
  content: "|";
  top: -21px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  left: 47px;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  display:block;
}
```

Finally it will be [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w64odd2n/)

```css
.pie,
.c100 .bar {
  position: absolute;
  border: 0.08em solid #307bbb;
  width: 0.84em;
  height: 0.84em;
  clip: rect(0em, 0.5em, 1em, 0em);
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.c100 {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 120px;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0.1em 0.1em 0;
  background-color: #cccccc;
}

.c100>span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 5em;
  line-height: 5em;
  font-size: 0.2em;
  color: #cccccc;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-transition-property: all;
  -moz-transition-property: all;
  -o-transition-property: all;
  transition-property: all;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  -o-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.c100:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.08em;
  left: 0.08em;
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  width: 0.84em;
  height: 0.84em;
  -webkit-transition-property: all;
  -moz-transition-property: all;
  -o-transition-property: all;
  transition-property: all;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  -o-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in;
}

.c100 .slice {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  clip: rect(0em, 1em, 1em, 0.5em);
}

.c100 .slice:before {}

.c100.p25 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.c100 .slice:before,
.c100 .slice:after {}

.pie,
.c100 .bar:after,
.pie,
.c100 .bar:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  box-shadow:
}

.c100 .bar:before {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  left: -10px;
  top: 47px;
  width: 10px;
}

.c100 .bar:after {
  content: "|";
  top: -21px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  left: 47px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="c100 p25"> <span>25%</span>
    <div class="slice">
      <div class="bar"></div>
      <div class="fill"></div>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>
```

You can just make changes in left and border width property to change the width.

Comment: Thanks for your time. but it works only for 25% and not when it comes to dynamic

Answer (score 2):

I tried this one, I think you can apply the same css to fill class and then change its clip to increase the arc size. If you are dynamically changing the clip value for bar class then you can do the same for fill too.

```css
.pie,
.c100 .bar {
  position: absolute;
  border: 0.08em solid #307bbb;
  width: 0.84em;
  height: 0.84em;
  clip: rect(0em, 0.5em, 0.5em, 0em);
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.c100 {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 120px;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0.1em 0.1em 0;
  background-color: #cccccc;
}

.c100 > span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 5em;
  line-height: 5em;
  font-size: 0.2em;
  color: #cccccc;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-transition-property: all;
  -moz-transition-property: all;
  -o-transition-property: all;
  transition-property: all;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  -o-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.c100:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.08em;
  left: 0.08em;
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  width: 0.84em;
  height: 0.84em;
  -webkit-transition-property: all;
  -moz-transition-property: all;
  -o-transition-property: all;
  transition-property: all;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  -o-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in;
}

.c100 .slice {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}

.c100.p25 .bar {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  z-index:101;
}

.c100.p25 .fill {
  position: absolute;
  border: 0.08em solid #fff;
  width: 0.84em;
  height: 0.84em;
  clip: rect(0em, 0.55em, 0.55em, 0em);
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="c100 p25"> <span>25%</span>
    <div class="slice">
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="fill"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

See the snippet here, if this can help

```css
.pie,
.c100 .bar {
    position: absolute;
    border: 0.08em solid #307bbb;
    width: 0.84em;
    height: 0.84em;
    clip: rect(0em, 0.5em, 1em, 0em);
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.c100 {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 120px;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0.1em 0.1em 0;
    background-color: #cccccc;
}

.c100 > span {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 5em;
    line-height: 5em;
    font-size: 0.2em;
    color: #cccccc;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-transition-property: all;
    -moz-transition-property: all;
    -o-transition-property: all;
    transition-property: all;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -o-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.c100:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.08em;
    left: 0.08em;
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    width: 0.84em;
    height: 0.84em;
    -webkit-transition-property: all;
    -moz-transition-property: all;
    -o-transition-property: all;
    transition-property: all;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    -o-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
}

.c100 .slice {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    clip: rect(0em, 1em, 1em, 0.5em);
}

.c100 .slice:before {}

.c100.p25 .bar {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.c100 .slice:before,
.c100 .slice:after {}

.pie,
.c100 .bar:after,
.pie,
.c100 .bar:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    box-shadow:
}
div.bar:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border: 0.08em solid #ffffff;
    width: 0.84em;
    height: 0.84em;
    clip: rect(0em, 0.5em, 1em, 0em);
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    box-sizing: content-box;
left: -0.1em !important;
    top: -0.08em !important;
}
```

```html
<body>
         <div class="c100 p25"> <span>25%</span>
              <div class="slice">
                <div class="bar"></div>
                <div class="fill"></div>
              </div>
           
          </div>

</body>
```

Comment: The arc doesn't look like it represents 25%.

Comment: Thanks for your time. but not much help when it comes to dynamically changing the value.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I can do. I have added before and after pseudo elements to `.slice` and added different clip values to them and a rotate of 90degrees to the before pseudo element. The pseudo elements are linked to the `.slice` CSS, so adjusting the rotation will adjust the after pseudo element as well.

```css
.pie,
.c100 .bar, .c100 .slice:before, .c100 .slice:after {
  position: absolute;
  border: 0.08em solid #307bbb;
  width: 0.84em;
  height: 0.84em;
  clip: rect(0em, 0.5em, 1em, 0em);
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.c100 .slice:before, .c100 .slice:after {
  content:" ";
  display:block;
  border: 0.08em solid #fff;
  z-index:2;
}
.c100 .slice:before {
  clip:rect(0.47em, 0.1em, 1em, 0em);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.c100 .slice:after {
  clip:rect(0em, 0.5em, 1em, 0.47em);
}

.c100 {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 120px;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0.1em 0.1em 0;
  background-color: #cccccc;
}

.c100>span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 5em;
  line-height: 5em;
  font-size: 0.2em;
  color: #cccccc;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-transition-property: all;
  -moz-transition-property: all;
  -o-transition-property: all;
  transition-property: all;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  -o-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.c100:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.08em;
  left: 0.08em;
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  width: 0.84em;
  height: 0.84em;
  -webkit-transition-property: all;
  -moz-transition-property: all;
  -o-transition-property: all;
  transition-property: all;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  -o-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in;
}

.c100 .slice {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  clip: rect(0em, 1em, 1em, 0.5em);
}

.c100.p25 .bar, .c100 .slice:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="c100 p25"> <span>25%</span>
  <div class="slice">
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="fill"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer which suggest to use `.bar:before` and `.bar:after` is wrong, because this object has no information about the beginning and end of the progress stripe.

Note, that the "clip" property has been used twice - first use is applied to the `.slice` and second to the `.bar` object. These "clips" define where are the beginning and the end of the stripe.

So, the solution is to use pseudoselectors on both:

```
.c100 .slice:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 5px;
    height: .08em;
    background-color: #fff;
    left: calc(50% - 3px);
    z-index: 2;
}

.c100 .bar:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Please check the working example:
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r7emrhv8/14/)